# HTML form not passing values to PHP (mysqli_real_escape_string)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, xampp

HTML

```
<form type="POST" action="includes/login.php">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="parola" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['email'])) 
    {
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    } 
else 
    {
        echo "Nu ati completat adresa de e-mail. <br />";
    }

if(isset($_POST['password'])) 
    {
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    } 
else 
    {
        echo "Nu ati completat parola. <br />";
    }

if(isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['password']))
{ 
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE password = '$password' AND email = '$email'");
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count_rows == 1)
    {
            $_SESSION["login"] = "OK";
            header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

    else
    {
        header("Location: ../login.php");

    }
}
?>
```

I tried switching from MySQL to MySQLi and I'm sure it's related to this. My form is not passing values to the PHP script even if the inputs have a name. Did some research here on StackOverflow and found many questions about forms not passing data but there was usually a typo or a missing name, which is not my case (I think).

(I know that the password is not secured yet, I'll add a SHA256 or something there soon so don't stress about it)

Tried echoing the query and it's just blank where the password and email address should be.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE password = '' AND email = ''
```

I also get this warning:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\breloc\includes\login.php on line 4

Line 4 in my script is:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` wouldn't work if a connection was not opened. Do the variables contain values if you don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`? why are you still using mysql and not mysqli ?:/

Comment: So I need to provide the link parameter as I provide for mysqli_query? ex: `mysqli_query($link, $query)`

Comment: give submit button a name and use code after buttons click

Comment: @MateiPanchios, precisely!

Comment: you have used $email variable for email and password both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change form `type="post"` to `method="post"`
2. Add database connection string to your `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

Answer (score 5):

make change to Your **form** tag

```
 <form type="POST">
```

to

```
 <form method="POST">
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Documentation http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php 
you must provide the mysqli ressource as first parameter of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `method` instead of `type` in your `<form>` tag, like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="includes/login.php">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="POST" action="includes/login.php">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="parola" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST[email]))
    {
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
    } 
else 
    {
        echo "Nu ati completat adresa de e-mail. <br />";
    }

if(!empty($_POST['password'])) 
    {
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['password']);
    } 
else 
    {
        echo "Nu ati completat parola. <br />";
    }

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{ 
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE password = '".$password."' AND email = '".$email."'");
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count_rows == 1)
    {
            $_SESSION['login'] = "OK";
            header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

    else
    {
        header("Location: ../login.php");

    }
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

set 'method' not type

```
<form method="POST" action="includes/login.php">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="parola" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

don't forget to connect to your db and pass the that connection to your mysqli_query and mysqli_real_escape_string functions

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

if(isset($_POST['email'])) 
    {
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    } 
else 
    {
        echo "Nu ati completat adresa de e-mail. <br />";
    }

if(isset($_POST['password'])) 
    {
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
    } 
else 
    {
        echo "Nu ati completat parola. <br />";
    }

if(isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['password']))
{ 
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE password = '$password' AND email = '$email'");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count_rows == 1)
    {
            $_SESSION["login"] = "OK";
            header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

    else
    {
        header("Location: ../login.php");

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

As from [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), the first parameter must be `mysqli resource`  and its missing within your code, and also change

```
<form type="POST">
```

into

```
<form method="post">
```

So your code looks like

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);// and been repeated at all those occurences
```

Comment: Reason for downvoting

Comment: i think <form type="post"> must be <form method="post">